# Console of the chrome is Javascript Engine?

Tags: javascript-engine

Console in Google Chrome is a example of Javascript Engine? If not, please tell me what is the most popular example of Javascript Engine. This is not my homework, i'm kinda confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please up this question. It helps a lot who wants to be a web developer. Please thanks.